# Order of function calls is an c++ arithmetic operation

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, order-of-execution

Suppose we have this code (seen in an interview test), the order of arithmetical operations is well defined in the standard (left to right), but the question is: the order of execution for the functions is defined (the same as for the operations) or this code is `undefined behavior`?

```
int test_b = 1;
int test_x() {test_b++; return test_b;}
int test_y() {test_b = 3; return test_b - 1;}
int test_z() {test_b = test_b+8; return test_b + 2;}

int a = test_x() - test_y() + test_z();
```

Please keep in mind that this question is not related to sequence points (we have function calls)

PS: I have tried few online compilers on https://godbolt.org/, from what I have tested the result is always 13.

Comment: *"the order of arithmetical operations is well defined in the standard (left to right)"* [Evaluation order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) and operator precedence are distinct things. Whereas precedence is defined, the evaluation order is unsequenced here.

Comment: Operator precedence and order of evaluation are not the same thing. See [Operator Precedence vs Order of Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473107/operator-precedence-vs-order-of-evaluation)

Comment: Well, exactly this is the question: knowing that operator precedence and order of evaluation are not the same thing, the order of evaluation is well defined ?

Comment: The "duplicate" answer is not a duplicate from my point of view, is related to sequence points as there is no "function call" layer that could change the order.

Comment: *"the order of execution for the functions is defined (the same as for the operations) or this code is undefined behavior?"* None of those, order is unspecified, but function cannot overlap, so modification of `test_b` doesn't lead to UB. Any permutations `x`, `y`, `z` might happens.

Comment: thank you @Jarod42 . But if the order of evaluation of x, y, z might happen, the result is UB (different results on different compilers).

this is not clear to me as this case is not related to sequence points (we have function calls)

Comment: @Jaro42 But, because the functions may be called in any order, then there ***is*** potential for UB. The value of `a` will depend on which order the functions are called in.

Comment: For info I have tested on a lot of compilers on https://godbolt.org/ but the order of execution seems to remain test_x, test_y, test_z.

Comment: @AdrianMole this is implementation defined, not undefined, behaviour, because the bodies of the functions are indeterminately sequenced, not unsequenced. It's the same rule that makes multiple `std::make_unique` calls exception safe

Comment: @AdrianMole There are plenty of dupes for this. For example, see [Order of function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737344/order-of-function-call)

Comment: @cprogrammer just because everywhere you checked does it one way doesn't make that way mandatory

Comment: @JasonLiam OK, that's a better duplicate.

Comment: The correct answer to the interview test is "I will never write code like this. Promise!".

Comment: @Caleth totally agree with you. This is why I have put the question here. But yes, is a duplicate, I didn't search well (found only seq points refs)

Comment: @Caleth: Pedantically, it is not even implementation defined, any order can happen at each call...

Comment: @Caleth *this is implementation defined* No, it is unspecified. The order of evaluations can even differ between invocations.

Comment: @j6t No, it cannot differ between invocations, that is cristal clear. I have checked the compiled result and is predictable. The only question is if this is predictable for all compilers
```
        rcall test_x()
        mov r16,r24
        mov r17,r25
        rcall test_y()
        sub r16,r24
        sbc r17,r25
        rcall test_z()
```

Comment: @cprogrammer If the expression `test_x() - test_y() + test_z()` were inlined at different call sites (because it occurs in an inline function, for example), then each site can choose a different evaluation order. I count that as "different between invocations".

Comment: It could be inlined, but 'rcall' doesn't sound like an inlined function.